# JSPDF - How to delete blank last page in pdf download

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I am using jspdf here.
I am getting a blank page while downloading the pdf.
When you click *submit1* button charts will generate,and when you press *download* button those chart will be downloaded as pdf.
Everything is working but a blank page is coming at last of the page.
Here is my [live demo in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3hJcC8pgzZxXPLWpfBw?p=preview). also here I have the html and javascript code

### html

```
<div><img id="logo" style="width:30%" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/3.png"/>dddddddd</div>
 <input type="button" id="download"  value="download" /> click to console
  <div><button id="button1" class="button1">submit1</button></div>
  <p id="bottom-content">footer</p>
```

### script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var index = 0;
    var id = [];
    $('#button1').on('click', function() {
        $('body').append($("<div id='chart" + index + "'></div>"));

        Highcharts.chart('chart' + index, {
           title: {
        text: 'Chart-'+index+''
    },
            series: [{
                data: [1, 2, 3]
            }]
        });
        var temp = "chart" + index + "";
        console.log(temp);
        id.push(temp);

        index++;
    });

    $('#download').on('click', function() {
console.log(id);
  var doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt', 'a4', true);
  var elementHandler = {
    '#ignorePDF': function(element, renderer) {
      return true;
    }
  };

  var source = document.getElementById("logo");
  doc.fromHTML(source, 15, 15, {
    'width': 200,
    'elementHandlers': elementHandler
  });

  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
   var elements = id;

 // console.log(xx);
  for (let i in elements) {


      let svg = document.querySelectorAll('svg');
      let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      let canvasIE = document.createElement('canvas');
      let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      let data1 = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg[i]);

      canvg(canvas, data1);
      let svgBlob = new Blob([data1], {
        type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
      });

      let url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

      let img = new Image();
      img.src = url;
      img.onload = function() {
        context.canvas.width = $("#"+elements[i]).find('svg').width();
        context.canvas.height = $("#"+elements[i]).find('svg').height();

        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        // freeing up the memory as image is drawn to canvas
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

        var dataUrl;
        if (isIEBrowser()) { // Check of IE browser 
          var svg = $(elements[i]).highcharts().container.innerHTML;
          canvg(canvasIE, svg[i]);
          dataUrl = canvasIE.toDataURL('image/JPEG');
        } else {
          dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        }

        doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'JPEG', 20, 150, 560, 350);

          let bottomContent = document.getElementById("bottom-content");
  doc.fromHTML(bottomContent, 15, 700, {
    'width': 560,
    'elementHandlers': elementHandler
  });

  let logo = document.getElementById("logo");
         doc.fromHTML(logo, 15, 200, {
    'width': 560,
    'elementHandlers': elementHandler
  });

  doc.addPage();

      };



    }


  setTimeout(function() {
    doc.save('TestChart"'+index+'".pdf');
  }, 1000);

});
});
function isIEBrowser() {
  var ieBrowser;
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

  if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // Internet Explorer
  {
    ieBrowser = true;
  } else //Other browser
  {
    console.log('Other Browser');
    ieBrowser = false;
  }

  return ieBrowser;
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the number of pages present in the document and then delete the last page

The following line will give you the number of pages present in the document:

```
var pageCount = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
```

The following code can be used to delete last page from the document:

```
doc.deletePage(pageCount)
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Till here  var pageCount = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
  alert(pageCount); its showing correct,but when I use doc.deletePage(pageCount) , alert is showing only 1 always and page is showing only one that is blank,If you can please edit in my plunker it will be very helpful for me

Comment: did you get the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Yes Thanks for your help,I need one more help that I need to display the logo in all pages of pdf while downloading,now its showing in first page.

Comment: you can add a custom function for adding new page and in that function handle all the header/footer requirements for that page... something like -- addNewPage(pageNo) { //code to add image goes here }

Comment: everywhere where you find a need to call 'doc.addPage()' method, call addNewPage(){//code to add logo ... doc.addPage()}

Comment: I am not getting ,I have edited inside loop like that but it not showing logo in the pages  pageCount = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
  function addNewPage(pageCount) { 
  let source = document.getElementById("top-content");
  doc.fromHTML(source, 15, 15, {
    'width': 200,
    'elementHandlers': elementHandler
  });
 } 
  doc.addPage(addNewPage); can you please edit in plunker

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Comment: doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'JPEG', 20, 150, 560, 350); --- use this line above doc.addPage()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183298/discussion-between-suhas-nm-and-carreankush).